# number of elements of the form $2^k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and consider the set $H:=\{1,2,\cdots, 3n\}$. How many elements of $H$ are of the form $2^k$, with $k\in\mathbb{N}$? I think that there are two cases to consider, namely: $n$ odd and $n$ even. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you solve $1 \le 2^k \le 3n$ for $k$ ?

Comment: Use function $L_n$ ($log_e$) for solve.

Answer (score 1):

We must find $k$  such that $ 2≤2^{k}<3n $ .so for solve it we can use logarithm function and the properties of this function.consider the function $log_2 x$ then :$ 2≤2^{k}<3n $ $\Rightarrow$ $1=log_2 2\le k=log_2 2^k < log_2 (3n) =log_2 3 + log _2 n$ then answer is $k=[log_2 3 +log_2n]$.

Comment: I would think that your strategy yields $1\leq k < \log_2(3n)$. In light of this, can you explain how you arrive at your conclusion that $k=\log_2(3n)$.

Comment: @cantor_paradise,note that $log_2 3n$ for every nature n is not  positive  integer number,because let $log_2 3n = k$ that k is positive nature number then $2^k = 3n $ it is contradiction for every n .

Comment: Note that [x] is part of integer of x.